ECM: adding I(0) to long-term relation
I have an ECM model where the long-term relation is between $y$ and $x_1$ that are both I(1) and cointegrated, i.e.
$y_t = a + b.x_{1,t} + \epsilon_t$
To this long-term relation, I need to add $x_2$ which is I(0) but has a large impact on $y$. Note $x_2$ impact $y$, not $\Delta y$ so it makes no sense to add $x_2$ to the short-term response. So, focusing on the long-term equation, having:
$y_t = \bar{a} + \bar{b}.x_{1,t} + c.x_{2,t} + \mu_t$
sounds correct. $y$ and $x_1$ are cointegrated so adding $x_2$ should have no impact on the model soundness. The residual is still I(0). My questions are:

Am I missing something? What would be the practical issue of adding $x_2$?

Would you have any literature on the topic? The literature is focus on I(1) processes but there is no reference about adding I(0) variable.

Alternatively, what about doing the following for the Long-Term:


Alternative Approach
$y_t = a + b.x_{1,t} + \epsilon_t$
regress $\epsilon_t$ on $x_2$ (essentially do a 2 steps regression) as
$\epsilon_t = d + e.x_{2,t} + \nu_t$
to get
$y_t = a + b.x_{1,t} + d + e.x_{2,t} + \nu_t$
and finally build the short-term response from $\nu_t$:
$\Delta y_t = \gamma \Delta x_{1,t} + \rho.\nu_{t-1}$

Continuing on the topic of adding an I(0) variable in the ECM model, I tested two options.
Option 1: introduce $x_2$ in the long-term equilibrium
$y_t = a_0 + a_1.x_{1,t} + a_2.x_{2,t} + \epsilon_t$
$\Delta y_t = \gamma_1 \Delta x_{1,t} + \gamma_2.\epsilon_{t-1}$
Option 2: introduce $x_2$ in the short-term response (with a 1 month to be consistent with Option 1)
$y_t = b_0 + b_1.x_{1,t} + \epsilon_t$
$\Delta y_t = \mu_1 \Delta x_{1,t} + \mu_2.x_{2,t-1} + \mu_3.\epsilon_{t-1}$
Findings

Option 1 behaves as expected: the model converges towards the LT equilibrium relationship. The "problem" is that mixing I(1) and I(0) could raised questions.

Option 2 follows Option 1 closely. The interesting part is that the LT equations are different meaning that Option 2 does NOT revert to its LT equilibrium. It reverts to (LT+$\mu_2.x_{2,t-1}$) which makes sense.

I tried to estimate the model using a single step approach as suggested but this gave me several issues such as: (1) non significant coefficient, (2) different forecasts, (3) coefficient values that can't be related to Option 1 or 2. The issue must come from the fact that the variables are not perfectly independent.

the alternative approach discussed above which introduce $x_2$ as a regressor of the residuals should give very similar result as Option 1 and 2.


I'd love your feedback

In view of the responses, I need to add some business context. Without the component x1, y would be I(0) and would be driven by x2 which is I(0). y is I(1) because the driver x1 added to the system is I(1). If x2 is fixed, y should not change, so x2 affects y but not its change.

Hi N.R: y is I(1) independently of what else is in the model so it's not the case that y would be I(0) witout $x_1$. The order of $y$ is what is it is and that doesn't change. I agree with Richard that you need a model that does what you want and I'm not sure but I don't think one exists. Richard makes the good point that you have an ECM implied by the cointegration relationship which implies that you can't just throw in an extra predictor that's I(0). Interesting question for sure but the answer eludes me ?

@mlofton. In practice $y$ is driven by $x_1$ and $x_2$. Example: $y$=profit, $x_1$=spending on innovation, and $x_2$=Unemployment rate. $y$ is function of both $x_1$ and $x_2$. A company not investing in innovation would have a stationary profit driven by $x_2$. Meaning $x_2$ has direct impact of the level variable $y$, not $\Delta y$.

N.R. This is a complex problem (which I DO NOT claim expertise on. apologies if I gave that impression  ) but I do know that you can't just throw the $x_{2t}$ into the original regression and still maintain the cointegrating relationship between $y_t$ and $x_{1t}$. This is because $x_{1t}$ and $x_2t$ will then both be involved in the estimation of $\beta$. To see it more easily: Think of the residual estimates of a regression with just $x_{1t}$ versus a regression including $x_{1t}$ and $x_{2t}$. They will definitely be different so the long term response changes.

or even more simply: LHS is I(1) and RHS is I(0) + I(1). Done.

I still don't quite follow Aksakal's approach and I got curious about I(0) + I(1) when I said it above and did find this. I don't have time to look at it and I suggest staying with Aksakal's approach ( assuming its fine ) but this looks related to your problem.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60328/time-series-one-i1-and-one-i0-variable-should-i-use-var-vec-test-for-coin

Also, take a look at Christopher Hanck's comment there about I(0). Maybe they can be included but I don't see how it doesn't change the effect of the I(1) variable.

Let's build ECM from ground up following a general idea in Engle, Granger (1987).

regress the non-stationary part on $x_1$:
$$ y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1t}+\varepsilon_t
$$

obtain the residuals $\hat\varepsilon_t $

regress the stationary part on $\Delta x_1,x_2$ and lagged residuals $\hat\varepsilon_{t-1}$:


$$\Delta y_t=\gamma_0+\gamma_1 \Delta x_{1t}+\gamma_2 x_{2t}-\gamma_\varepsilon\hat\varepsilon_{t-1}+\nu_t$$
Where $\gamma_\varepsilon$ is the volocity of error correction.
You can estimate this model in one step though. Plug the residuals into the second equation:
$$\Delta y_t=\gamma_0+\gamma_1 \Delta x_{1t}+\gamma_2 x_{2t}-\gamma_\varepsilon(y_{t-1}-\beta_0-\beta_1 x_{1,t-1})+\nu_t$$
$$y_t=(1-\gamma_\varepsilon)y_{t-1}+(\gamma_0+\gamma_\varepsilon\beta_0)+\gamma_1 x_{1t}+\gamma_2 x_{2t}+(\gamma_\varepsilon\beta_1-\gamma_1) x_{1,t-1} +\nu_t$$
Which is familiar ARX(1) model, aka ARIMA(1,0,0) with exogenous variables:
$$y_t=\phi_1 y_{t-1}+c+\gamma_1 x_{1t}+\gamma_2 x_{2t}+\gamma_{11} x_{1,t-1} +\nu_t$$
$$\phi_1=1-\gamma_\varepsilon\\
c=\gamma_0+\gamma_\varepsilon\beta_0\\
\gamma_{11}=\gamma_\varepsilon\beta_1-\gamma_1
$$
Make sure that the error correcting velocity satisfies: $0<(\hat\gamma_\varepsilon=1-\hat\phi_1)<2$
Note, that you can recover the slope $\hat\beta_1$ but not intercepts $\hat\gamma_0,\hat\beta_0$ of the original system of equations from a single AR(1) model specification.
Here's an example of the business problem where this could be applicable: we think that the balance $y_t$ of the deposit account is dependent on the stock prices $p_t$ and interest rates $r_t$. In this case, $y_t,p_t$ are often modeled as I(1), but $r_t$ is I(1) only in a short term while in long horizon it's more like I(0). So, for a long run forecast we could apply the model that I described.
Look up Greene, Econometric Analysis, 7th ed, section 21.3.2 for more detailed discussion.

Thank you for the feedback. I shall try to run some analysis with the one-step approach and see how it behaves.

@Aksakal: Two questions on your approach. Why do you use the lagged residuals in the error correction part of the model ? Are you sure that you take the error correction model and just throw in an extra variable, $x_2$, that is I(0) and not effect the estimation of the error correction model. The ECM is implied by the regression on $y_t$ which doesn't contain $x_2$.  Is there some place where this is  discussed ( adding an I(0) to a cointegrating relationship ) because what you did is interesting and I've never seen it before. Thanks.

Oh, when you said "familiar AR(1)", did you mean ARDL(1, something ) because there are $x's$ in there also. I forget the ARDL convention so "something" is evading my memory.

@mlofton, corrected to ARX(1) i.e. ARIMAX(1,0,0)

@mlofton, I find Engle Granger (1987) approach to be intuitive when explaining ECM for cointegrated series, and used it here. You don't need to follow this, of course. The idea is that the error in previous period informs the correction in this period. You can estimate this system with observed data. If you plug this period's error how would you estimate the parameters?

@mlofton, as to a place where this is discussed - I'm not sure. I believe Greene has a discussion that outlines a similar approach, but could be a bit more abstract than  my explanation.  See section 21.3.2 in Cointegration topic.

Thanks Aksakal. If you find Engle-Granger to be intuitive, you're blessed. ( and I could see you do by the way you went from coint  to ecm ). I'll check out Greene if it's not in storage. Really impressive stuff. I just wish it had a name but it might not. How about Aksakal-EG-one step ? Thanks again.

Oh, I'm not sure of the notation for ARIMAX but, in the ARDL world  of notation, the first number is the number of lags of Y and the second number is the number of lags of X. It's not important. The important thing is the equation itself.

Richard: Aksakal can answer better than I but I think his equation is including the non-cointegrated  variable and still maintaining the ECM relationship. It's related to the lagged residuals. I have a pdf of greene somewhere and will attempt to read it  but this may have to go on my "I hope to understand some day" list.

Aksakal: I looked at your derivation more closely and maybe I'm not seeing something but $\gamma_2 x_{2t}$ can't stay $\gamma_2 x_{2t}$ you modify the series so that the response is $y_t$ rather than $\Delta y_{t}$. I'm not sure what the fix is because, as you know, he wants $x_{2t}$ to be a function of $y_{t}$ and not the difference of $y_t$.

Aksakal: To be more clear, when you go from $\Delta y_t$ to $y_t$, you do the same un-delta-fying on $x_{1t}$ but $x_{2t}$ stayed the same. Doesn't that need to be un-delta-fied also ? I don't know if doing that is the answer because he wanted the $x_{2t}$ effect on $y_{t}$ and not the change.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Aksakal. I appreciate it. I found a pdf but I need to see what the edition is. Hold on a moment. and then we can chat ? Of course, I could be not understanding something which is fine with me. Just checked and edition is too old. It's from 2002.

I don't want to waste your time chatting until after I've done a proper reading in Greene so it's probably best if we hold off chatting. It's upto you. If you want to, I can but it may not be productive.

First, it is impossible that $x_2$ affects $y$ but not $\Delta y$. Given the history of $y_t$ up to time $t-1$, what affects $y_t$ will also affect $\Delta y_t$; after all, the latter is the same $y_t$ minus a predetermined constant, $y_t-y_{t-1}=\Delta y_t$. In this regard, $y$ and $\Delta y$ are two sides of the same coin.
A long-term relationship is by definition between integrated variables. Adding an I(0) variable to it could not be called a long-term relationship anymore.
So how to model a mixture of I(1) and I(0) variables? This has been asked many times on Cross Validated, and I have answered quite a few such questions. Briefly, you want to keep both sides of a model's equation at the same order of integration, and it is convenient to make that I(0). (Remember that first differences of I(1) variables are I(0) and the error correction term (as a unit) is I(0), too.) If one side is I(0) while the other is I(1), they will diverge from each other, so the model will be incoherent.
Update following an update of the OP: I think your first approach is fine. If I remember correctly, in the equations with integrated variables, you cannot trust the usual estimates of standard errors (?) and $p$-values. However, if you rewrite the model in the (V)ECM form, including any stationary variables as they are (outside the error-correction term), the standard estimates will be just fine. This is in line with my earlier answers quoted above.

Hi Richard. Thank you for your input. I have added a general comment to be more precise. Without the component x1, y would be I(0) and would be driven by x2 which is I(0). y is I(1) because the driver x1 added to the system is I(1). If x2 is fixed, y should not change, so x2 affects y but not its change. This is the reason why I would need to add x2 to the long-term equilibrium relationship. I understand your suggestion and I understand that my approach is a deviation from the classic one but the for model to make business sense x2 should in the long-term equilibrium and I need to support this

@N.R, my answer is about the statistical relationships between the variables, and VECM is used for that. When you say Without the component x1, y would be I(0), are you referring to causality between them? If so, perhaps you should look at a different class of models.

@R.H.. Yes, in my case, x1 and x2 impact y directly. Since x1 is I(1) and x2 is I(0) then y is also I(1). I'd like to understand why it would be incorrect to add x2 to the LT beside the fact that it is not documented in the literature. Alternatively, would it be okay to (1) built the LT with x1, (2) fit the resulting residuals of with x2, (3) built the short-term response? I understand it is not the classic approach but would this be wrong? Which alternative class of models would you suggest?

@N.R, I am not sure about an alternative class of models. I just do not think the statistical models that I am familiar with can reflect what you are interested in. It may be possible to write the model the way you like, but then there would still exist another (classical) representation of the model where $x_2$ is not included in the error correction term. Perhaps you should try to write the model fully (by editing your post), and then we could take a look at it and see if there is anything self-contradictory about it.

@R.H, I have edited my post to clarify it and explain the alternative approach I am considering.

@N.R, I think your first approach is fine. If I remember correctly (my knowledge of VARs and VECMs is getting rusty), in the equations with integrated variables, you cannot trust the usual estimates of standard errors (?), $t$-statistics and $p$-values. However, if you rewrite the model in the (V)ECM form, including any stationary variables as they are, the standard estimates will be just fine. This is in line with my earlier answers I quote in my answer.

@N.R, I was too quick to declare my first point. It was a knee-jerk reaction from a forecasting course I have recently been teaching. There, forecasting $y_t$ and $\Delta y_t$ is one and the same. But for relationships between one of these variables and another variable $x_{2,t}$, your point makes sense.
